# Why does TypeScript prohibit a private setter for a public getter of the same name?

Tags: typescript

Having a public getter and a private setter of the same name is prohibited in TypeScript, as already discussed in various questions here on SO.

My main programming language is C#, where this is perfectly fine. I also consider it a useful construct, and to be honest, I don't really see what a problem could be with allowing this in TypeScript as well.

**Why does TypeScript prohibit this? This question is not about workarounds or alike, I just want to know the reason for this design.**

Edit: A code sample can be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825350/private-setter-typescript).

Comment: can you provide some code , what you were working on.?

Comment: @Viplock: Why is that necessary? This is a general question, not a question about a specific program.

Answer (score 5):

There is a comment from one of TypeScript authors: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2845#issuecomment-176990923

> Accessors are symetrical with properties in the type system. anything
>   we do will need to be manifested in the type and expressible on
>   properties. Adding new access modifiers to enable
>   private_set/public_get would increase the complexity of the language
>   and the learning curve, and the value gained from this would not match
>   the added complexity.