# What are the differences between the private keyword and private fields in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, class, private, encapsulation, class-fields

In TypeScript 3.8+, what are the differences between using the `private` keyword to mark a member private:

```
class PrivateKeywordClass {
    private value = 1;
}
```

And using the `#` private fields [proposed for JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields):

```
class PrivateFieldClass {
    #value = 1;
}
```

Should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: [The future of the "private" keyword in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670).

Comment: TLDR of @str's link (at least when it comes to my main concern): "Our current plan is to leave the current private behavior as-is."

Answer (score 178, accepted):

## Private keyword

The [private keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-private) in TypeScript is a **compile time** annotation. It tells the compiler that a property should only be accessible inside that class:

```
class PrivateKeywordClass {
    private value = 1;
}

const obj = new PrivateKeywordClass();
obj.value // compiler error: Property 'value' is private and only accessible within class 'PrivateKeywordClass'.
```

However compile time checking can be easily bypassed, for example by casting away the type information:

```
const obj = new PrivateKeywordClass();
(obj as any).value // no compile error
```

The `private` keyword is also not enforced at runtime.

#### Emitted JavaScript

When compiling TypeScript to JavaScript, the `private` keyword is simply removed:

```
class PrivateKeywordClass {
    private value = 1;
}
```

Becomes:

```js
class PrivateKeywordClass {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 1;
    }
}
```

From this, you can see why the `private` keyword does not offer any runtime protection: in the generated JavaScript it's just a normal JavaScript property.

## Private fields

[Private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields) ensure that properties are kept private **at runtime**:

```js
class PrivateFieldClass {
    #value = 1;

    getValue() { return this.#value; }
}

const obj = new PrivateFieldClass();

// You can't access '#value' outside of class like this
obj.value === undefined // This is not the field you are looking for.
obj.getValue() === 1 // But the class itself can access the private field!

// Meanwhile, using a private field outside a class is a runtime syntax error:
obj.#value

// While trying to access the private fields of another class is 
// a runtime type error:
class Other {
    #value;

    getValue(obj) {
        return obj.#value // TypeError: Read of private field #value from an object which did not contain the field
    }
}

new Other().getValue(new PrivateKeywordClass());
```

TypeScript will also output a compile time error if you try using a private field outside of a class:

[image: Error on accessing a private field]

Private fields originates from a [TC-39 ECMAScript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields)  and are part of the 2021 ECMAScript specification, which means that they can be used in both normal JavaScript and TypeScript.

#### Emitted JavaScript

If you use private fields in TypeScript and are targeting ES2021 or older versions of JavaScript for your output, TypeScript will generate code that emulates the runtime behavior of private fields using [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) ([source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#caveats)).

```js
class PrivateFieldClass {
    constructor() {
        _x.set(this, 1);
    }
}
_x = new WeakMap();
```

If you are targeting anything later than ES2021, TypeScript will emit the private field:

```js
class PrivateFieldClass {
    constructor() {
        this.#x = 1;
    }
    #x;
}
```

## Which one should I use?

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

The `private` keyword is a fine default. It accomplishes what it was designed to accomplish and has been used successfully by TypeScript developers for years. And if you have an existing codebase, you do not need to switch all of your code to use private fields. This is especially true if you are not targeting `esnext`, as the JS that TS emits for private fields may have a performance impact. Also keep in mind that private fields have other subtle but important differences from the `private` keyword .

However if you need to enforce runtime privateness or are outputting `esnext` JavaScript, than you should use private fields.

Also keep in mind that organization/community conventions on using one or the other will also evolve as private fields become more widespread within the JavaScript/TypeScript ecosystems.

### Other differences of note

- Private fields are not returned by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and similar methods
- Private fields are not serialized by `JSON.stringify`
- There are importance edge cases around inheritance

  TypeScript for example forbids declaring a private property in a subclass with the same name as a private property in the superclass.

  ```
  class Base {
      private value = 1;
  }

  class Sub extends Base {
      private value = 2; // Compile error:
  }
  ```

  This is not true with private fields:

  ```
  class Base {
      #value = 1;
  }

  class Sub extends Base {
      #value = 2; // Not an error
  }
  ```

- A `private` keyword private property without an initializer will not generate a property declaration in the emitted JavaScript:

  ```
  class PrivateKeywordClass {
      private value?: string;
      getValue() { return this.value; }
  }
  ```

  Compiles to:

  ```js
  class PrivateKeywordClass {
      getValue() { return this.value; }
  }
  ```

  Whereas private fields always generate a property declaration:

  ```
  class PrivateKeywordClass {
      #value?: string;
      getValue() { return this.#value; }
  }
  ```

  Compiles to (when targetting `esnext`):

  ```js
  class PrivateKeywordClass {
      #value;
      getValue() { return this.#value; }
  }
  ```

#### Further reading:

- [The future of the "private" keyword](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670)
- [TypeScript PR that added private fields](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30829)

Answer (score 26):

## Use cases: `#`-private fields

Preface:

- [TC39 proposal class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)
- Synonym terms: `#`-private, hard private, run-time private

#### Compile-time *and* run-time privacy

`#`-private fields provide compile-time *and* run-time privacy, which is  not "hackable". It is a mechanism to prevent access to a member from outside the class body [in any direct way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.0-dev.20200110#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oGIwC5oDsBXAWwCMBTAJwG5UNpgB7fCAF0sOFccoApcCJCpQCUiOvQysAFgEsIAOmzQAvNDC00GAL6oJ6AA6FSIWcAASYfABMQ5ACqNYvMci2Tolcq0KV80GXklMGgAelDoRgAzBkZfCHIAGgC5GDZZEBBoAHceAGsIZNJCVk9yAEdCWS80xmJyaCieYkiY2Rtq8i5ZZn1oXRQB1DtSpsY8eDV8cmy4XgAWACYRTTHg6jCIqkoeZPxGUrBMxmzya0iSiFlrBtBIGFJGa1lyCFReMfUYKwBPESVSGAaJtoOlMgRGAZyAo9ChUEA).

```
class A {
    #a: number;
    constructor(a: number) {
        this.#a = a;
    }
}

let foo: A = new A(42);
foo.#a; // error, not allowed outside class bodies
(foo as any).#bar; // still nope.
```

#### Safe class inheritance

`#`-private fields get a unique scope. Class hierarchies can be implemented without accidental overwrites of private properties with equal names.

```
class A { 
    #a = "a";
    fnA() { return this.#a; }
}

class B extends A {
    #a = "b"; 
    fnB() { return this.#a; }
}

const b = new B();
b.fnA(); // returns "a" ; unique property #a in A is still retained
b.fnB(); // returns "b"
```

TS compiler fortunately emits an error, when `private` properties are in danger of being overwriten (see [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.0-dev.20200110#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oFgBQ0PQMRmgXmgCIxCBuNTaAMwDtYAKASkWgCcBTAFwFdWbpOACwCWEAHQ5S0AL5pZqNKEgwAQtHYAPTuxoATGPAQVMOfEQBGZFOky0VTFhx58BI8ZJly0igPY0InNDmZjTsAO7Q9ozkqMB+ED4g7GIgPgDm9OZitAyM0dAA9AVsXLz+RCTQUtw0wgCO3OzQAA6sPs3srJwAnti4wvzwotABwiAgJZxgA+y6vv6JyakZWXZM+UWTZTCEltabWAC0rcIAbmDa0MM19Y3eseBQcABMLMYYJ+eXuATEZO-UOgOJBOMquURiMBSeTyRSPVSvTTaPQGV5ITYAFQAytAwmA+DBuDAhBcWm0Ol1emkuDAfKdOmFWMJOMixNZKJ8Lk0fhYrAC1swQaUXEIIVDPKhYbF4oFzK8CKEIipnkwYnEFkkUulMs9skC8lJNqCCbz5glNcsdXqohtisbyrtCGhNqTWDVDpxhABbJqtdqdHoVQjUNpeyKvOkMpnaHaVKihl5oIA)). But due to the nature of a compile-time feature everything is still possible at run-time, given compile errors are ignored and/or emitted JS code utilized.

#### External libraries

Library authors can refactor `#`-private identifiers without causing a breaking change for clients. Library users on the other side are protected from accessing internal fields.

#### JS API omits `#`-private fields

Built-in JS functions and methods ignore `#`-private fields. This can result in a more predictable property selection at run-time. Examples: `Object.keys`, `Object.entries`, `JSON.stringify`, `for..in` loop and others ([code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.0-dev.20200110&ssl=6&ssc=49&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoGIBGYATtALzQAsATANwbbQEBep0ARABYCuXrGAvhgzB4AOwjwQAUwB0IeAHMAFAHk8AK0nAALtIDWkgJ4RFIyQHc4iRQEpb0APT3oAbTZNW0ALqD0QA); see also Matt Bierner's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59641565/5669456)):

```
class Foo {
    #bar = 42;
    baz = "huhu";
}

Object.keys(new Foo()); // [ "baz" ]
```

---

## Use cases: `private` keyword

Preface:

- [`private` keyword in TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-private)
- Synonym terms: TS private, soft private, compile-time private

#### Access to internal class API and state (compile-time only privacy)

`private` members of a class are conventional properties at run-time. We can use this flexibility to access class internal API or state from the outside. In order to satisfy compiler checks, mechanisms like type assertions, dynamic property access or [`@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) may be used amongst others.

Example with type assertion (`as` / `<>`) and `any` typed variable assignment:

```
class A { 
    constructor(private a: number) { }
}

const a = new A(10);
a.a; // TS compile error
(a as any).a; // works
const casted: any = a; casted.a // works
```

TS even allows dynamic property access of a `private` member with an [escape-hatch](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12111#issuecomment-259568490):

```
class C {
  private foo = 10;
}

const res = new C()["foo"]; // 10, res has type number
```

Where can private access make sense? (1) unit tests, (2) debugging/logging situations or (3) other advanced case scenarios with project-internal classes (open-ended list).

Access to internal variables is a bit contradictory - otherwise you wouldn't have made them  `private` in the first place. To give an example, unit tests are supposed to be black/grey boxes with private fields hidden as implementation detail. In practice though, there may be valid approaches from case to case.

#### Available in all ES environments

TS `private` modifiers can be used with all ES targets. `#`-private fields are only available for `target` `ES2015`/`ES6` or higher. In ES6+, `WeakMap` is used internally as downlevel implementation (see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/)). Native `#`-private fields currently require `target` `esnext`.

#### Consistency and compatibility

Teams might use coding guidelines and linter rules to enforce the usage of `private` as the only access modifier. This restriction can help with consistency and avoid confusion with the `#`-private field notation in a backwards-compatible manner.

If required, [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) (constructor assignment shorthand) are a show stopper. They can only be used with `private` keyword and there are [no plans](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30829#issuecomment-569723465) yet to implement them for `#`-private fields.

#### Other reasons

- `private` might provide better run-time performance in some down-leveling cases (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670#issuecomment-497370201)).
- There are no hard private class methods available in TS up to now.
- Some people like the `private` keyword notation better .

---

## Note on both

Both approaches create some kind of nominal or branded type at compile-time.

```
class A1 { private a = 0; }
class A2 { private a = 42; }

const a: A1 = new A2(); 
// error: "separate declarations of a private property 'a'"
// same with hard private fields
```

Also, both allow cross-instance access: an instance of class `A` can access private members of other `A` instances:

```
class A {
    private a = 0;
    method(arg: A) {
        console.log(arg.a); // works
    }
}
```

---

Sources

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/#ecmascript-private-fields
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30829