# What does Angular 10 hashes in class fields mean?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I'm used to seeing hashes in older Angular (< 10) versions in the HTML templates to declare DOM elements as variables.

But in Angular 10 I found examples where hashes are used inside component classes.

```
class Product {

  #name: string;

  get name(): string {
    return this.#name;
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how it works?

Comment: where is that example ? provide the relevant link ?

Comment: It's not part of Angular, see https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Private properties in JavaScript ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes)

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641564/what-are-the-differences-between-the-private-keyword-and-private-fields-in-types

Answer (score 0):

It's a way to mark fields as private. This function is experimental. Some browsers does not support it.