# How to define method overloads for a method that is public and other that is private in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, oop, overloading, access-modifiers

I have a class that have some static methods in it, and I want to keep the same name between a public method and a private one, how can I overload it?

```
export class MyClass {

    public static methodX(arg: ArgTypeA): void {
        // method implementation, it will call the private method methodX(arg: ArgTypeB)
    }

    private static methodX(arg: ArgTypeB): void {
        // method implementation
    }

}
```

Comment: I provided an answer, but I suspect this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). There's probably a better way to structure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: It's probably true, I'll try to think in a better structure, but thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You may only one value for each property key on anything. This is true for plain objects, and it's true for class instance methods and it's true for static class methods.

So you my *not* have two methods with the exact same name where one is `private` and one is `public`. They must have different names.

Such as:

```
export class MyClass {

    public static methodX(arg: ArgTypeA): void {
        // method implementation, it will call the private method methodX(arg: ArgTypeB)
    }

    private static methodXCoreImplementation(arg: ArgTypeB): void {
        // method implementation
    }

}
```

---

One way to achieve something close to this would be [to use private fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641564/what-are-the-differences-between-the-private-keyword-and-private-fields-in-types). That uses the `#` prefix to declare a private field which is completely inaccessible to the outside.

And `foo` is technically a different property name to `#foo`, so this should work:

```
export class MyClass {
    public static methodX(arg: string): void {
        this.#methodX(arg)
    }

    static #methodX(arg: string): void {
        console.log('hello from private field method:', arg)
    }
}

MyClass.methodX('test') // "hello from private field method:",  "test"
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false&ts=4.9.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkCeBhVDOAbwCg4K4wBXAIyQEsE40YUYm4BbYGACwgATABoAKFFADmALhYwoDAHaSAlLIBuEBoJLlK+-gzQA6AMQ9+QsRNV6KAX1J257Tud4CR4qbNYLlanCa2rr6+ggQimgQSMDGSBCSogDkfMBICXAAZlAQXFQK6uzA2QzpOhae0skANHA2Ks6OjqS4BOgmlVYpMMCsySpwAPRDcABEaRkQ2bn5YIXFpeXcHkLSY3XjvaxjQA)

Comment: I didn't know that "#" in JavaScript/TypeScript was a thing